# Content Subscriber Timer Job is not publishing content types to all site collections in a web application with multiple content databases

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, central-administration

**Scenario:**  We have a web application that has multiple site collections and multiple content databases? (30 Site collections, 3 content databases) For example purpose lets name the content databases as follows: wss_content_db1, wss_content_db2 and wss_content_db3.

**Problem:** When we publish a content type from the CT Hub, it only pushes the content type to the site collections living in wss_content_db1, none of the other site collections living in other content databases are receiving these content types.

Any thoughts/suggestions will be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved this by restarting all the SharePoint services on all the servers (not just WFEs) and after re-publishing a content type it made it to all the subscriber site collections. Not exactly sure what seemed to have fixed it but for now it is not an issue.